# Laravel Eloquent: 3 table relationship

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm new to Laravel-eloquent, I would like to translate this SQL to Eloquent mode:

```
select
    fl.id, fut.id, fut.firebase_topic_id, ft.id, fl.created_at
from
    firebase_logs fl,
    firebase_user_topics fut,
    firebase_topics ft
where
    fl.id = fut.firebase_log_id
    and
    fut.firebase_topic_id = ft.id
    and
    fl.created_at between '2019-01-09 16:33:39' and '2019-01-09 16:33:41'
    and
    ft.id = 1
    order by fl.created_at asc
```

Where:

```
Firebase_logs.id (1) -> Firebase_user_topics.firebase_log_id (N)
and
Firenase_user_topics.firebase_topic_id (N) -> Firebase_topics.id (1)
```

**FirebaseLog.php:**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class FirebaseLog extends Model
{
    public $incrementing = false;
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    public function user_topics() {
        //return $this->hasManyThrough(FirebaseTopics::class, FirebaseUserTopics::class);
        return $this->hasMany(FirebaseUserTopics::class);
    }
}
```

**FirebaseUserTopics.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class FirebaseUserTopics extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'firebase_user_topics';

    public function log()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(FirebaseLog::class);
    }

    public function topic()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(FirebaseTopics::class);
    }    
}
```

**FirebaseTopics.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class FirebaseTopics extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'firebase_topics';

    public function user_topics()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(FirebaseUserTopics, 'firebase_user_topics');
    }
}
```

My Controller, works fine with this:

```
$a = FirebaseLog::with('user_topics')->whereBetween('created_at', array('2019-01-09 16:33:39', '2019-01-09 16:33:41'))->get(); 
return $a;
```

But I don't know how to connect to **FirebaseTopics** to continue building the code, some help will be appreciated.

Comment: if you give more details about relation of your tables, i think, someone can helpful easy.

Comment: @FGDeveloper next to SQL I wrote the table relations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDITED ANSWER!**

The solution of your problem is use the `hasOne` relation instead of `belongsTo` in your FirebaseUserTopics model. It must be following;

```
public function topic()
{
    return $this->hasOne(FirebaseTopics::class, 'id', 'firebase_topic_id');
}
```

Because your `FirebaseTopics` model has not a relation with `FirebaseUserTopics` model.  The "belongsTo" (that uses to make reverse a relation) search `firebase_topic_id` field in the `firebase_topics` table but this field has no in the `firebase_topics` table. That's why, you must be make to relation directly, not reverse.

Comment: The "topic" is null, I think because the "topic" function is from "FirebaseUserTopics" and not from "FirebaseLog"

Comment: Yes, ``topic`` function is a ``FirebaseUserTopic``' model's function, normally you should be access to it from ``user_topics`` function. Because, the ``topic`` function has a relation with ``FirebaseTopics`` model. How and where did you get that ``null`` return? If you used my example foreach, it may be returning ``null`` for first row. Can you check your data?.

Comment: the foreach has an error: `.ERROR: Property [topic] does not exist on this collection instance` and the first one returns "null" in the "topic" field: https://i.imgur.com/Y4oluMU.png

Comment: Did you try ``hasOne`` instead of ``belonsTo`` in FirebaseUserTopics model?

Comment: with hasOne and foreach: `Property [topic] does not exist on this collection instance` and with hasOne without foreach: `Unknown column 'firebase_topics.firebase_user_topics_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `firebase_topics` where `firebase_topics`.`firebase_user_topics_id` in (1))`

Comment: Can you try, ``$this->hasOne(FirebaseTopics::class, 'id', 'firebase_topic_id')`` in your ``FirebaseUserTopics``'s topic method.

Comment: This is my answer already. :) But i edited my answer by true solution